# After stop typing call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a search via ajax on onkeyup in the input. But I am getting one problem it is taking input word one by one like I type matrix then it will search for m then ma then mat then matr so on. I want my function call after stopping keypress in input like I type matrix and stop typing then it will go search. Is there any solution for it?

I am calling this function like that

```
onkeyup="showmovie(this.value)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  _.debounce is working for me

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to wrap that inside a function. Now your code will call showmovie function immediately. Try this one:

```js
onkeyup="function() { showmovie(this.value) }"
```

Comment: The problem is debouncing